# ZFS Ubuntu 20.04 , unable to change files even as root : Operation not permitted

Tags: ubuntu, files, permissions, zfs, acl

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 , now I can no longer rename / delete files without

: Operation not permitted

SELinux is disabled

I have not noticed any ACL settings on the files
lsattr
-------------------- tvshow.nfo

but the affected folders are showing a -a- and I can not seem to change them

```
-----a--------------
```

I can still write new files but then can not alter them

I have tried applying

```
setfacl -b
chattr -i

sudo rm tvshow.nfo 
rm: cannot remove 'tvshow.nfo': Operation not permitted

rm tvshow.nfo 
rm: cannot remove 'tvshow.nfo': Operation not permitted

getfacl tvshow.nfo
# file: tvshow.nfo
# owner: aio
# group: aio
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx



lsattr
-------------------- tvshow.nfo

#sudo zfs get all
ZFS3WAY                                         type                        filesystem                  -
ZFS3WAY                                         creation                    Wed Dec 11 22:20 2019       -
ZFS3WAY                                         used                        1.45T                       -
ZFS3WAY                                         available                   11.7T                       -
ZFS3WAY                                         referenced                  1.05T                       -
ZFS3WAY                                         compressratio               1.26x                       -
ZFS3WAY                                         mounted                     yes                         -
ZFS3WAY                                         quota                       none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         reservation                 none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         recordsize                  128K                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         mountpoint                  /ZFS3WAY                    default
ZFS3WAY                                         sharenfs                    off                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         checksum                    on                          default
ZFS3WAY                                         compression                 lz4                         local
ZFS3WAY                                         atime                       off                         local
ZFS3WAY                                         devices                     on                          default
ZFS3WAY                                         exec                        on                          default
ZFS3WAY                                         setuid                      on                          default
ZFS3WAY                                         readonly                    off                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         zoned                       off                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         snapdir                     visible                     local
ZFS3WAY                                         aclmode                     passthrough                 local
ZFS3WAY                                         aclinherit                  passthrough                 local
ZFS3WAY                                         createtxg                   1                           -
ZFS3WAY                                         canmount                    on                          default
ZFS3WAY                                         xattr                       sa                          local
ZFS3WAY                                         copies                      1                           default
ZFS3WAY                                         version                     5                           -
ZFS3WAY                                         utf8only                    off                         -
ZFS3WAY                                         normalization               none                        -
ZFS3WAY                                         casesensitivity             sensitive                   -
ZFS3WAY                                         vscan                       off                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         nbmand                      off                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         sharesmb                    off                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         refquota                    none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         refreservation              none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         guid                        1670362542889147666         -
ZFS3WAY                                         primarycache                all                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         secondarycache              all                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         usedbysnapshots             408G                        -
ZFS3WAY                                         usedbydataset               1.05T                       -
ZFS3WAY                                         usedbychildren              309M                        -
ZFS3WAY                                         usedbyrefreservation        0B                          -
ZFS3WAY                                         logbias                     latency                     default
ZFS3WAY                                         objsetid                    54                          -
ZFS3WAY                                         dedup                       off                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         mlslabel                    none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         sync                        standard                    default
ZFS3WAY                                         dnodesize                   legacy                      default
ZFS3WAY                                         refcompressratio            1.25x                       -
ZFS3WAY                                         written                     4.31M                       -
ZFS3WAY                                         logicalused                 1.82T                       -
ZFS3WAY                                         logicalreferenced           1.31T                       -
ZFS3WAY                                         volmode                     default                     default
ZFS3WAY                                         filesystem_limit            none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         snapshot_limit              none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         filesystem_count            none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         snapshot_count              none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         snapdev                     hidden                      default
ZFS3WAY                                         acltype                     posix                       local
ZFS3WAY                                         context                     none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         fscontext                   none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         defcontext                  none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         rootcontext                 none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         relatime                    off                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         redundant_metadata          all                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         overlay                     on                          default
ZFS3WAY                                         encryption                  off                         default
ZFS3WAY                                         keylocation                 none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         keyformat                   none                        default
ZFS3WAY                                         pbkdf2iters                 0                           default
ZFS3WAY                                         special_small_blocks        0                           default
```

Comment: Is the partition mounted for read/write? Sg. like this: `mount | grep $(df . | tail -1 | (read Mnt _; echo "$Mnt"))` should return `/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)` where `rw` means read/write. Edit: show the output of `ls -ld .` -- to delete a file, you have to have write-permission for the containing directory.

Comment: ls -ld tvshow.nfo
-rwxrwxrwx 1 aio aio 14757 Dec  8 06:39 tvshow.nfo

Comment: mount | grep $(df . | tail -1 | (read Mnt _; echo "$Mnt"))
ZFS3WAY on /ZFS3WAY type zfs (rw,noatime,xattr,posixacl)

Comment: thanks for your help I do not what has changed in the last few hours but

chattr -R -a /ZFS3WAY
seemed to have finally worked